# Linux Mint something wrong with my .bashrc

Tags: linux, bash, linux-mint, android, bashrc

The path of my .basrc file is

```
/home/vamsi/.bashrc
```

It is weird that my file has nothing but the path I set. I think I am using a file at the wrong location or that I have lost my `.bashrc` file as none of the environment variables set here seem to work.

```
#ANDROID_DEV
ANDROID_HOME=/opt/android-sdk-linux
export ANDROID_HOME
PATH= $PATH:$ANDROID_SDK_HOME/tools
export PATH
PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools
export PATH
PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/build-tools
export PATH

#MAVEN-PATH
M2_HOME=/opt/apache-maven-3.1.0
export M2_HOME
M2=$PATH:$M2_HOME/bin
export M2
```

I was prompted to install maven2 in order to use mvn, but the android command cannot be found.
Could you please help me find a solution to this issue.

EDIT:

Meanwhile,I tried this:

```
export PATH=${PATH}:/opt/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools
export PATH=${PATH}:/opt/android-sdk-linux/tools
```

Now,the output of $PATH echoes:

```
bash: /usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/opt/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools:/opt/android-sdk-linux/build-tools: No such file or directory
```

NOW WORKING:
1. Used `ANDROID_HOME` instead of `ANDROID_SDK_HOME`
2. Removed space between `= $PATH`
3. Ran `echo $PATH`
4. Logged out and logged back in
5. Opened the terminal and tried `android list targets`

Comment: What are you trying to do? If "vamsi"is your username, .bashrc is in right place.

Comment: what does echo $PATH give you?

Comment: What has android do with your computer? Explain your problem

Comment: I would like to add the Android sdk path to my environment variables in linux as I would like to try developing apps with ant and the sdk using a text editor of my choice.

Comment: Your `.bashrc` is almost fine, there is one error, there should be no space between `PATH= $PATH`, change that to `PATH=$PATH`. To check if an environment variable has been set, run `echo $PATH`, not `$PATH` by itself. Now, what exactly do you want to add to your path and what makes you think it is not working?

Comment: As a side note, `PATH` is usually set at login time for example in `.bash_profile`, not `.bashrc`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't defined `$ANDROID_SDK_HOME` in the code you pasted. You only defined `$ANDROID_HOME`

edited to reflect terdon's comment.

Comment: +1 for `ANDROID_SDK_HOME` but the error is because the OP ran `$PATH` not `echo $PATH`, it does not mean the directory does not exist.